# What is the lovasz theta number of complement of Grötzsch graph?

Tags: graph-theory, quantum-computation

Lovasz theta number: (It is said to be polynomial, but I do not know how to computer it)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number

Grötzsch graph:[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph

I would like to know the Lovasz number of the complement Groetzsch graph.

Comment: Sage says it is 2.3997084

Comment: where can i find Sage? Thanks!

Comment: Found it, still downloading, I am new in Sage, could you maybe share with me your code? Thanks!@Jernej

Comment: sage: graphs.GrotzschGraph().complement().lovasz_theta()
2.3997084